# Why won't my switch statements correctly output asterisks in my C++ program?

Tags: c++, for-loop, switch-statement, break

The program is supposed to output vertical and horizontal lines of varying lengths using asterisks. The number of asterisks and direction they will go is decided by the user in an input statement. It must be created using switch statements. Here's my current code:

```
int main() {

    // Variables
    int length = 1;
    char direct;

    // User input choice
    if (length >= 1 && length <= 20) {
        cout << "\nEnter the line length and direction: ";
        cin >> length >> direct;
    }

    // If user input incorrect
    else {
        system("pause");
    }

    // Switch cases for horizontal or vertical
    switch (direct) {
    case 'h': for (int count = 0; count <= length; count++) {
        cout << "*";
        break;
    }
    case 'H': for (int count = 0; count <= length; count++) {
        cout << "*";
        break;
    }
    case 'V': for (int count = 0; count <= length; count++) {
        cout << "*" << "\n" << endl;
        break;
    }
    case 'v': for (int count = 0; count <= length; count++) {
        cout << "*" << "\n" << endl;
        break;
    }

    default:  cout << "Illegal comand" << endl;

    }

    system("pasue");
}
```

Here's what one of my horizontal choice output statements looks like:

```
Enter the line length and direction: 4 h
***

*

Illegal Command
```

Here's what one of my vertical choice output statements looks like:

```
Enter the line length and direction: 4 v

*

Illegal Command
```

Here's what I want the horizontal one to look like:

```
Enter the line length and direction: 4 h

****
```

Here's what I want the vertical one to look like:

```
Enter the line length and direction: 4 v

*
*
*
*
```

Why are the asterisks not outputting correctly? Why does it output "Illegal Command" every time? Also thought I should note that I am a beginner when it comes to C++. Thanks!

Comment: Please try to [learn how to debug your code](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), if you do the problem should be obvious. Hint: Where are the `break` statements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the `break;` statements in the wrong place.

```
case 'h': for (int count = 0; count <= length; count++) {
    cout << "*";
    break;
}
```

needs to be;

```
case 'h': for (int count = 0; count <= length; count++) {
    cout << "*";
  }
  break;
```

Please note that you have the same logic for `h` and `H`. You can combine them.

```
case 'h':
case 'H':
  for (int count = 0; count <= length; count++) {
    cout << "*";
  }
  break;
```

You can combine the cases `v` and `V` similarly.

You can still improve on it by creating helper functions to write the horizontal lines and the vertical lines.

```
case 'h':
case 'H':
  writeHorizontalLine(length);
  break;

case 'v':
case 'V':
  writeVerticalLine(length);
  break;
```

where

```
void writeHorizontalLine(int length)
{
   for (int count = 0; count <= length; count++)
   {
      cout << "*";
   }
   cout << endl;
}

void writeHorizontalLine(int length)
{
   for (int count = 0; count <= length; count++)
   {
      cout << "*" << endl;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! All of this helped a ton :)

Answer (score 3):

Try putting the break keyword out of the curly braces in each switch condition.

do this

```
case 'V': for (int count = 0; count <= length; count++) {
        cout << "*" << "\n" << endl;

    }
break;
```

instead of

```
case 'V': for (int count = 0; count <= length; count++) {
            cout << "*" << "\n" << endl;
            break;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

write break statement outside the for loop.If you write the break statement inside the for loop in case then it comes out of for loop .Illegal command encounters because u haven't used break outside the for loop